# How to add text to a rectangle in SVG?

Tags: svg

I am trying to put the word "fox" inside this blue rectangle, but it just doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<html>
<body>

<svg width="400" height="200">
<rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:0;fill-opacity:0.7;stroke-opacity:0.1">

<text fill="#44ffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="150" y="96">fox</text>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your <rect> tag is open. That's probably not the reason but your SVG contains invalid XML unless you change the `<rect ...>` to `<rect .../>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment, your XML is invalid. The well-formed XML

```
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:0;fill-opacity:0.7;stroke-opacity:0.1" />
  <text fill="#44ffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="150" y="96">fox</text>
</svg>
```

works for me.